# Front End and Backend Login Doesnt work Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, login

My magento site is at this link: 
http://frisbeemarketing.com/mom2b/customer/account/login/ 
the login page does not work and it does not send an error it just reloads

It seems like a problem with the REST API since that link is not found: 
https://frisbeemarketing.com/mom2b/api/rest/products

i don't know what to do next with his info
i am a bit of a beginner and would need a step by step answer

Answer (score 1):

Please check your cookie domain settings in Magento backend

Goto `System -> configuration -> General -> Web -> Session Cookie Management`
check what is set in `Cookie Domain`

There should be `frisbeemarketing.com`